# Не могу понять синтаксис объявления функций

Tags: c, функции, указатели, типы-данных

Иногда в исходиниках на си натыкаюсь на такое объявление функций

```
any_type *(*function_name)(arg1 int, arg2 int);
```

Или конкретный пример отсюда https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.c#L124

```
zend_string *(*accelerator_orig_zend_resolve_path)(zend_string *filename);
```

Непонятно здесь то, почему перед именем функции стоит указатель и почему оно взято в скобки: `(*function_name)`

Comment: Это не функция, а указатель на функцию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Стоит указатель", чтобы показать, что это — *указатель* на функцию, а взято в скобки потому, что без них это рассматривалось бы как функция, возвращающая указатель. Например,

```
int * f();    // Функция, возвращающая указатель на int
int (* f)();  // Указатель на функцию, возвращающую int
```